# Python dictionary creation error

Tags: python, python-2.5

I am trying to create a Python dictionary from a stored list. This first method works

```
>>> myList = []
>>> myList.append('Prop1')
>>> myList.append('Prop2')
>>> myDict = dict([myList])
```

However, the following method does not work

```
>>> myList2 = ['Prop1','Prop2','Prop3','Prop4']
>>> myDict2 = dict([myList2])
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 3; 2 is required
```

So I am wondering why the first method using append works but the second method doesn't work? Is there a difference between `myList` and `myList2`?

#### Edit

Checked again `myList2` actually has more than two elements. Updated second example to reflect this.

Comment: "Is there a difference between myList and myList2?" What does `myList == myList2` say?  Both of those methods work for me with Python 2.5.

Comment: I'm not seeing this error with either 2.5.2 or 3.1.1 - sure there isn't a typo somewhere? These lists should be identical.

Comment: it works for me on Python 2.6.2

Comment: They both work for me.  I'm guessing that in the second example you didn't actually type the square brackets in `dict([mylist2])`.  Are you sure you didn't write `dict(mylist2)`?

Comment: The 2nd method worked fine for me on two systems.  One runs 2.4.3 and the other 2.6.  I tried to look up bugs on the Python.org pages, but for some reason, the link on the Python page to the bugtracker isn't working for me.

Comment: As others have said, your code as posted should work.  But the way you're populating `myList` and using it in the `dict()` constructor implies that you're doing the wrong thing with it, and the error you get supports that implication.  The most likely issues are that `myList2` has more than two elements in it, or that you are not wrapping `myList2` in another iterable when you pass it to `dict()`.  Either of these would be solved if you used a 2-tuple instead of a list here, since that is a better structure to represent a key-value pair.

Comment: Ah yes, as I suspected, you're using `myList2` as a general purpose list.  That's incorrect -- as you're using it, it needs to have exactly two elements (a key and a corresponding value).

Comment: Ironically, you mis-spelt "dictionary" !!!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're doing it wrong.

The `dict()` constructor doesn't take a list of items (much less a list containing a single list of items), it takes an iterable of 2-element iterables.  So if you changed your code to be:

```
myList = []
myList.append(["mykey1", "myvalue1"])
myList.append(["mykey2", "myvalue2"])
myDict = dict(myList)
```

Then you would get what you expect:

```
>>> myDict
{'mykey2': 'myvalue2', 'mykey1': 'myvalue1'}
```

The reason that this works:

```
myDict = dict([['prop1', 'prop2']])
{'prop1': 'prop2'}
```

Is because it's interpreting it as a list which contains one element which is a list which contains two elements.

Essentially, the `dict` constructor takes its first argument and executes code similar to this:

```
for key, value in myList:
    print key, "=", value
```

Comment: Thanks just as I needed and now I realize if I have a list of keys I can create the dictionary with: myDict = dict(zip(myList,zeros(len(myList)))). If I don't have the values yet.

Comment: @Azim: Yes, that's a good approach.  The point is, when you create the `dict`, you need to provide *some* value for each key.  You can always go back and change the value later.