# python list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a simple code to fetch users from db using sqlalchemy and return them as json. My problem is how to format the output to get something like this:

```
{"results": [{"id":1, "username":"john"},{"id":2,"username":"doe"}]}
```

my code outputs an error which I cant seem to fix being a newbie in python:

```
d = []

for user in Users.query.all():
    v = {}
    for columnName in Users.__table__.columns.keys():
        v[columnName] = getattr( user, columnName )

    d.append( v )

return jsonify( d )
```

The code says:

```
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 11; 2 is required
```

Thanks.

Comment: In which line do you get this error?

Comment: Could you paste the whole stacktrace?

Comment: Not the reason for your error, but if you want to have that data structure, you need to change the return line to: return jsonify( {"results": d} )

Comment: didnt managed to get that far  Baltasarq but i'm aware of that

Comment: Full stack trace at: http://paste.pocoo.org/show/397870/
Full code at: http://paste.pocoo.org/show/397871/

Comment: Also, you're using a property that's supposed to be private (`__table__`), there are [other ways](http://code.google.com/p/pycopia/source/browse/trunk/storage/pycopia/db/models.py#1436) to get that metadata, using the API plus some helpers.

Comment: Ack! Looking at your pasted code, I see that you've called your function `list`. Don't do that! You're masking the `list` constructor. That might not be causing your current problem, but it will cause problems later.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ah, now that your code has been pasted, I can see that the fundamental problem is indeed coming from `jsonify`. The below workaround should be satisfactory.

```
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps({"results": [{"id":1, "username":"john"},{"id":2,"username":"doe"}]})
'{"results": [{"username": "john", "id": 1}, {"username": "doe", "id": 2}]}'
```

Replace `jsonify` with `json.dumps`, and let me know if that doesn't fix the problem.

But if you'd prefer to use `flask.jsonify`, then you should take a look at the `flask` documentation. The argument to `jsonify` should be the same as the argument to any [dict constructor](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.jsonify) -- i.e. a dict or an iterable of tuples. So that's the problem.

Comment: BTW, simplejson lets you [register additional encoders](http://simplejson.github.com/simplejson/#encoders-and-decoders) with it so you can extend it with more complex objects.

Answer (score 10):

I solved this error by simply saying

```
return jsonify( results = d )
```

instead of

```
return jsonify( d )
```

Comment: Nice. The reason behind this is that the jsonify in flask will not encode a raw array (in square brackets) at the top level. I don't know exactly why, but that is considered unsafe.

Answer (score 0):

The error is what you'd expect when creating a dict incorrectly - see [Python dictionary creation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615501/python-dictionary-creation-error)

Edited: See answer from senderle that identifies the root cause...

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `dict()` with `*args`, which is going to expand args to positional parameters. That is a typical cause of that error you are seeing. Leave that out.

Comment: He is somewhere, or is being called with some parameters he provided.