# TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__' on Python2.6

Tags: python

I'm attempting to run a Nessus Scan on a list of IPs in a python script. The list of IPs in a text file is passed as an argument when the script is ran. I have tried many different things including pynessus, but nothing seems to work for me. Any idea why I receive this error?

This is the error I receive: **OLD**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./pyList.py", line 47, in <module>
    nessus = API('https://127.0.0.1:8834', username='user', password='pass')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nessus/__init__.py", line 1265, in __init__
    self.login(self.username, password)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nessus/__init__.py", line 1318, in login
    self.post('login', data=payload)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nessus/__init__.py", line 1288, in post
    return self.__request('POST', name, **payload)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nessus/__init__.py", line 1291, in __request
    request = Request(method, self.base_url + name, **payload)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 86, in __init__
    self.headers = dict(headers or [])
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

**EDITED NEW ERRORS**
I updated Python which fixed those errors and produced 2 new ones. These are the New Errors I receive:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 23, in <module>
    print nessus.users.list()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nessus/__init__.py", line 323, in list
    return self.api.get(self.uri+'/list')['users']['user']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 25, in <module>
    nessus.scan.new(target, 'testing', '13')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nessus/__init__.py", line 670, in new
    payload['target'] = ','.join(target)
TypeError: sequence item 1: expected string, type found
```

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from subprocess import call
import whois
import sys
import nmap
from nessus import API

import requests
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()

#Stores results in text file
log = open("Results.txt", 'w')
sys.stdout = log

#Scanning
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as fp:
        for line in fp:
                print line
                print "\nNessus Results:"

                nessus = API('https://127.0.0.1:8834', username='user', password='pass')
                print nessus.users.list()
                target = ['localhost', list]
                nessus.scan.new(target, 'testing', '13')

                print "-------------------"

fp.close()
log.close()
```

Comment: `headers` needs to be a dict or an iterable of 2-items... What's the value of `headers`?

Comment: @Jon Clements I'm sorry I'm a bit new to python. What do you mean by that comment?

Comment: It looks like your Python install might be messed up. You have some packages coming from `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/` and some coming from `/usr/lib/python2.7`.

Comment: Can you [edit] your post to include the value of `headers`?

Comment: Have a read through [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615501/python-dictionary-creation-error) to see if it helps to explain what you should be looking for.

Comment: ```nessus.scan.new(target, 'testing' '13')``` — shouldn't there be a comma between ```'testing'``` and ```'13'```?

Comment: @JonClements: Unlikely; that call doesn't come from the OP's code. It's 5 layers down the call stack, across 2 libraries the OP didn't write.

Comment: The line numbers in the stack trace don't match the line numbers in the code you've posted. Could you run the code you posted and show us the stack trace that produces?

Comment: @user2357112 I updated Python and edited my code which produced a new error shown above. Any ideas?